# multiline sed to extract string terminated by a single quote

Tags: sed

I have numerous M4 macro files from which I wish to extract a single instance of file path if present.

In each file there is either a single line

```
define(`XSETROOT', `some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir1/subdir2/filename')
```

or spread over two lines

```
define(`XSETROOT', dnl
`some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir1/subdir2/filename')
```

or no entry at all.

So I wish to find the line starting

```
define(\`XSETROOT',
```

and then from the same line or next line extract the string which is bounded by "space" and "single quote", viz

```
SOME_DIR/subdir/subdir/filename
```

Can this be done without resorting to multiple sed invocations?

Additional information (formatting in comment field below appears not to work) --

In, the easy case when everything is on the same line, the problem of the quotes can overcome by suitable quoting/unquoting and this expression works

```
sed -ne 's|define(`XSETROOT'\'',.*`.* \(.*\)'\''.*|\1|p' file.m4
```

Further information --

Thanks to the response by MvG shewing how to do multiline processing, when the data is split over two lines, this expression works

```
sed -ne '/define(`XSETROOT/{n;s|`.* \([^'\'']*\)'\'').*|\1|p}' file.m4
```

But the question remains, is it somehow possible to construct an expression which will work with the data on one or two lines, or do I have to try one to see if there is a string returned and if not then try the other one to see if that returns a string?

Comment: I know how to do it, but dealing with all those various quotes is just killing me. I can't get my command to work because of this :(

Comment: In the case where everything is on the same line, this works to overcome the single quote problem <pre><code>sed -ne 's|define(`XSETROOT'\'',.*`.* \(.*\)'\''.*|>\1<|p' Theme.m4</pre></code>   so the part that I need the help for is how to deal with on the same line or next line if that is possible with a single invocation

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk` it might work for you:

```
awk -F "[`']" 'BEGIN { RS=")" } { print gensub(".* ","","g",$4) }' INPUTFILE
```

See (almost the same - as Ideone.com does not support CLI arguments) [in action here](http://ideone.com/xO2hm).

Explanation:

1. `` -F "[`']" `` sets the field separator to the regex of `` [`'] `` (any of those two quote characters)
2. `RS=")"` sets the record separator so this way we can have multiline records
3. `gensub(".* ","","g",$4)` returns everything from the 4th field after the last space in it

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I specifically wanted to learn how to do this with sed, as I prefer to use awk for processing columns of data rather than line editing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -n "/define(\`XSETROOT'/{/dnl/N;s/.* //;s/'.*//;p}"
```

- Do nothing unless the current line contains `` define(`XSETROOT' ``.
- If the line also contains `dnl`, then append the next line.
- Remove everything up to the last space.
- Remove everything after the last single quote.
- Print the remaining string.

The restriction of the `N` command to cases where there actually is a `dnl` serves two purposes: It allows a single line definition to match at the end of the file, and it allows two subsequent definitions where the first only takes one line.

Comment: Something is not quite right in that expression because it results in "dnl" being printed out and not the filename string.

Comment: Strange, if works for me and my GNU sed 4.2.1. Can you drop the `s///` commands and see if this results in both lines being printed?

Comment: sed --version  GNU sed version 4.2.1    So trying with file containing on two separate lines define(`XSETROOT',              dnl
`hsetroot -tile FVWM_DIR/themes/Crystal/Plaster-Pale_Blue.jpg') dnl using  sed -n "/define(\`XSETROOT'/{/dnl/N;}"   $X11_DIR/share/fvwm/themes/Crystal/Theme.m4   produces no output at all.

Comment: Dropping the -n results in the whole file being output.

Comment: When you drop the `s///`, don't drop the `p` as that's what prints the result. So try `sed -n "/define(\\`XSETROOT'/{/dnl/N;p}"` ans see whether that prints both lines.

Comment: In the code you included in your question, based on this answer, you use `n` instead of `N`. This will overwrite the first line with the second line, instead of appending to it, so the code will no longer work for the single-line case. Maybe simply turning that `n` into an `N` is enough for you. But take care of the part of my answer describing why I only execute `N` if there is a `dnl` so yiu can decide whether ignoring that is OK for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to use M4 itself.

```
m4 -D XSETROOT='some suitable value with a/path/to/a/file' file.m4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following SED script:

```
/^define(`XSETROOT/!d
/')$/!n
s/^.\+ \(.\+\)')$/\1/p
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
sed -n -e '/^define(`XSETROOT/!d; /'"'"')$/!n; s/^.\+ \(.\+\)'"'"')$/\1/p' file.m4
```

If we take the following data sample:

```
define(`XSETROOT', `some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir1/subdir2/filename1')                                                                                                          

foo bar stuff

define(`XSETROOT', dnl 
`some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir3/subdir4/filename2')

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

define(`XSETROOT', `some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir4/subdir5/filename3')

foo bar stuff

define(`XSETROOT', dnl 
`some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir5/subdir6/filename4')

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

define(`XSETROOT', `some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir6/subdir7/filename5')

foo bar stuff

define(`XSETROOT', dnl 
`some_command with parameters SOME_DIR/subdir7/subdir8/filename6')

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

... the output would be:

```
SOME_DIR/subdir1/subdir2/filename1
SOME_DIR/subdir3/subdir4/filename2
SOME_DIR/subdir4/subdir5/filename3
SOME_DIR/subdir5/subdir6/filename4
SOME_DIR/subdir6/subdir7/filename5
SOME_DIR/subdir7/subdir8/filename6
```